Does there exist a topological space s.t. $\pi_1(X) = S_n$ where $S_n$ is the symmetric group on $n$-letters?
I had a half-semester course on basic homotopy theory last spring. We discussed the fundamental group quite extensively, but we never provided an example where the fundamental group of a topological space equaled the symmetric group on $n$-letters. Is it possible to construct a topological space $X$ such that $\pi_1(X) = S_n$? (I implicitly assume that $X$ can be made path-connected by selecting one of its path components.)
Edit 1: Is there no way I can take a wedge sum of circles to form $*_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z$ and then stitch in 2-cells to add the appropriate relations that would give me $S_n$? I have not checked, but I assume that $S_n \subset *_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z$ can be found by some identification. I was hoping to form a space that at least vaguely resembled a topological manifold.
Edit 2: I found this link Group presentation of $S_n$. I imagine this would produce an algorithmic way for attaching $2$-cells to the CW-complex (or rather 1-skeleton) at that point. Does the resultant space equal the configuration space for $n$ points? Does it have a more familiar structure (e.g., genus-g surface, nonorientable surface, etc...). I may be totally wrong, but I would imagine this would entail attaching $\frac{n}{2} + 3$ 2-cells to only two 1-cells. I imagine that this attaching would ruin any manifold structure that could possibly arise.

In fact you can construct a topological space whose fundamental group is any group you like. You just take a presentation of the group by generators and relations. Then construct a cell complex with a unique $0$-cell, a $1$-cell for each of the group generators and then glue in a $2$-cell for each of the relations. This Corollary 1.28 in Hatcher's Algebraic Topology.

Thanks @Manuel Araujo, I think I'm confused about the sorts of two cells to add that would convert $*_{i=1}^n \mathbb Z$ to $S_n$. Is there any way to visualize them? I added an edit to my post to clarify.

Denote the $1$-skeleton by $X_1$ (a wedge of circles, one for each generator). If the relation is $x_1^{\epsilon_1}\cdots x_n^{\epsilon_n}=1$, where $x_i$ are generators and $\epsilon_i$ are signs, then the $2$-cell is attached via the map $S^1\to X_1$ which you construct by subdividing the circle into $n$ arcs. Then each of these arcs is mapped to the circle corresponding to the generator $x_i$, traversed in the direction specified by the sign. This is all explained in detail in Hatcher's book.

@Talmsmen : Explicit presentation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group#Generators_and_relations. You may have trouble with explicit visualization. The relation $\sigma_i^2 = 1$ means that there is a cross-cap attached to each edge. (The diagram of the cross-cap cut along its plane of symmetry is the thing you should imagine glued (twice) to each 1-cell.) The second relation glues a torus to each pair of 1-cells. The last relation glues something like a 3-layer cross-cap (thrice) to pairs of "adjacent" 1-cells.

Thanks @EricTowers. Although $\mathbb{RP}^2$ has a manifold structure, would it be possible to impose a manifold structure to the resultant cell complex we develop? I just can't imagine how all of the 2-cells (which I think of surfaces) could intersect at a single boundary line and still resemble $\mathbb R ^ n$. Is there some result that says otherwise?

@Talmsmen : The difficulty is really one of trying to visualize this 2-manifold embedded in $\Bbb{R}^3$.  $\Bbb{RP}^2$ can be embedded in $\Bbb{R}^4$ by only using the fourth coordinate in a tiny ball around the self-intersection. For sufficiently large $n$, the embedding into $\Bbb{R}^n$ has no self-intersections (so, for instance, the set of double-points in the cross-cap are actually at different coordinates in the larger embedding space).  I think that $n=4$ (or $5$, by some version of an embedding theorem) should be sufficient, but this taxes most people's visualization capabilities...

@ManuelAraújo I saw that you added an deleted the statement, "If you do this for the symmetric group, you will obtain a space which is weakly homotopy equivalent to the one described by Naïm Favier (but not homeomorphic)." Do you think that there are spaces besides the configuration space of $n$ unlabeled points in $\mathbb R^\infty$ that are weakly homotopic to $\pi_1(X)$?

That was wrong, that's why I deleted it.

Thanks for all of your help. I really appreciate it.

Yes: the configuration space of $n$ unlabeled points in $\mathbb{R}^\infty$.

Thanks. Are there no such cases when the space is path connected?

That space is path-connected.

Thank you, I haven't heard much about the configuration space. I'm still a mathematical novice. Is there a textbook that you would recommend on the subject? My course went primarily out of Munkres but assigned readings (and a few practice problems) from Hatcher.

I'm curious if just $\mathbb{R}^2$ is sufficient, given that that gives plenty of room for a homotopy of ordered configurations to swap two points.

OK, I see on the page you linked that just $\mathbb{R}^2$ gives the braid group $B_n$ as $\pi_1$ of the configuration space.  I wonder if just going up to $\mathbb{R}^3$ is enough to collapse the braid group into $S_n$.

@Daniel: yes, $\mathbb{R}^3$ is sufficient. You can show by induction on a suitable sequence of fiber bundles that the configuration space of $n$ ordered points in $\mathbb{R}^d, d \ge 3$ is simply connected. So it's the universal cover of the configuration space of $n$ unordered points in $\mathbb{R}^d$, and this is a Galois cover with Galois group $S_n$.
